# PDF renderer for iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, pdf, graphics

Mayb do you know a good open-source pdf renderer for objective-c? :)

Comment: Why not use UIWebView which is capable of displaying PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Graphics provides a lot of native PDF-rendering functionality. If you just want to provide a view that lets the user pan and zoom around a PDF, use a `UIWebView`; all you have to do is give it the URL to a PDF inside your bundle, as in

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_file" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: That should not be NSString * url, it should be NSURL * url.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to draw into a PDF, take a look at the section on [PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) in the Quartz 2D Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com) Not sure if this can be used on the iphone though and you may need to check the licensing for redistribution.